# Unable to perform login for scraping with Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

my first time asking a question here so please bear with me if I'm not providing everything that is needed.

I'm trying to build a spider that goes to this website (https://newslink.sg/user/Login.action), logs in (I have a valid set of username and password) and then scrape some pages.

I'm unable to get past the login stage.

I suspect it has to do with the formdata and what I enter inside, as there are "login.x" and "login.y" fields when I check the form data. The login.x and login.y fields seem to change whenever I log in again.

This question and answer seems to provide a hint of how I can fix things but I don't know how to go about extracting the correct values.

[Python scrapy - Login Authenication Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841409/python-scrapy-login-authenication-issue)

Below is my code with some modification.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request

class BtscrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "btscrape"
    #allowed_domains = [""]
    start_urls = [
        "https://newslink.sg/user/Login.action"
    ]


    def start_requests(self):
        return [scrapy.FormRequest("https://newslink.sg/user/Login.action",
                                   formdata={'IDToken1': 'myusername',
                                   'IDToken2': 'mypassword',
                                   'login.x': 'what do I do here?',
                                   'login.y': 'what do I do here?'
                                   },
                                   callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):
        return Request(
        url="webpage I want to scrape after login",
        callback=self.parse_bt
        )

    def parse_bt(self, response): # Define parse() function.
        items = [] # Element for storing scraped information.
        hxs = Selector(response) # Selector allows us to grab HTML from the response (target website).
        item = BtscrapeItem()
        item['headline'] =  hxs.xpath("/html/body/h2").extract() # headline.
        item['section']  =  hxs.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]").extract() # section of newspaper that story appeared.
        item['date'] =  hxs.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()").extract()# date of publication
        item['page'] =  hxs.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/text()").extract() # page that story appeared.
        item['word_num']  =  hxs.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]").extract() # number of words in story.
        item['text'] =  hxs.xpath("/html/body/div[@id='bodytext']/text()").extract() # text of story.

        items.append(item)
        return items
```

If I run the code without the login.x and login.y lines, I get blank scrapes.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons:

1. You don't send a `goto: https://newslink.sg/secure/redirect2.jsp?dest=https://newslink.sg/user/Login.action?login=` form parameter
2. You need cookies for auth part

So I recommend you to rewrite it this way:

```
start_urls = [
    "https://newslink.sg/user/Login.action"
]


def parse(self, response):
    yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        formnumber=1,
        formdata={
            'IDToken1': 'myusername',
            'IDToken2': 'mypassword',
            'login.x': '2',
            'login.y': '6',
        },
        callback=self.after_login,
    )
```

Scrapy will send `goto` automatically for you. `login.x` and `login.y` is just cursor coordinates when you click on a Login button.

Comment: I would skip the login form, and instead use the cookies and session to scrape the pages,